# Replace fragment when activity is onStop state

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a question about replace fragments in activity. If possible replace fragment when activity is onStop state?

I use restApi which send request to server and when we have response we change fragment in app, but sometimes when rest not finish work and user go out from app to phone desktop, app is crashed. How resolve this problem and change fragment when activity is onStop state?

Comment: What restApi are you using, what stack trace you get on your adb log file ?

Comment: I use Retrofit restApi, but my main question is if is possible replace fragment when activity is onStop state?

Answer (score 0):

you should use **Tread** for call rest and every Tread can fix time for answer. if web service or API or any kind of server stuff not did not send answer the **Tread** will go to a special state without any problem.